# Erro estranho no For em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá, meu amigo.

Estou com um erro muito besta que nem to conseguindo entender porque está errado.

```
a = [1, 4, 5]
b = []
for i in range(0,len(a)):
  c = a[i+1]
  b.append(c)
```

O erro é

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

como assim o copilador não entende que i = 0, eu quero a[1]??

Obrigado pela atenção

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicação de como está atualmente:

```
a = [1, 4, 5]
b = []
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    c = a[i+1] # primeiro 1, depois 2 e depois 3, você não tem a posição 3 no seu list a, você tem as posições 0, 1 e 2
    b.append(c)
```

Se for transferir os valores, um código melhor seria:

```
a = [1, 4, 5]
b = []
for i in a:
    c = a[i]
    b.append(c)
```

Aqui tem exemplos com estruturas de repetição com range e outras maneiras
http://curso.grupysanca.com.br/pt/latest/repeticao.html

Answer (score 1):

Por você utilizar o +1 dentro dos colchetes, quando o i do for chega na última posição, ele tenta acessar uma posição inexistente.
Ou você faz o range entre -1 e len(a)-1 ou remove o +1
Caso você deseje pular a primeira posição, basta fazer o range começar de 1 (também é preciso remover o +1)